# How to add conditional button in template field gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have one `gridview` that contains some fields, I want to show button in TemplateField when **Process** field has value.
Here is my code:

```
  <asp:GridView ID="grdList" PageSize="20" runat="server" DataSourceID="ODList" AllowPaging="True"
        AllowSorting="True" PagerSettings-Position="Top" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        ShowFooter="True" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" OnPageIndexChanged="grdList_PageIndexChanged">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="MeasureCatalogId" SortExpression="MeasureCatalogId" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="MeasureName"  SortExpression="MeasureName" />                
             <asp:TemplateField SortExpression="Process">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Process") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LevelId") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>             
            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%if(????????) -- want condition for process!= ""
                      {
                    %>
                      <img class="semPopup" sempopupurl='<%=Constant.AppPath %>/forms/baseform/MeasureProcessFromCatalogForm.aspx?t=2&lid=<%# Eval("LevelId") %>&mid=<%# Eval("MeasureCatalogId") %>'
                                    sempopupwidth="<%=width %>" sempopupheight="<%=height %>"
                                    src="../../App_Themes/images/select2.gif" />
                    <%} %>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <PagerSettings Position="Top"></PagerSettings>
        <PagerStyle CssClass="grid_pager" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to the other recommendations; you could try using a code expression on the field:

```
   <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
            <ItemTemplate>                
                  <img class="semPopup" sempopupurl='<%=Constant.AppPath %>/forms/baseform/MeasureProcessFromCatalogForm.aspx?t=2&lid=<%# Eval("LevelId") %>&mid=<%# Eval("MeasureCatalogId") %>'
                                sempopupwidth="<%=width %>" sempopupheight="<%=height %>"
                                src="../../App_Themes/images/select2.gif" Visible='<%# ShowButton(Eval("Process")) %>'/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

I have not tried this out, but it follows a similar pattern to what i have previously used. The code expression calls the codebehind function 'ShowButton' which should return a bool, here you can evaluate the value of process passed in, and if it is to your liking, pass back a true value; otherwise return false and the button will not show.

C#

```
protected bool ShowButton(object DataItem)
    {
        //Here you can place as many conditions as you like 
        //Provided you always return either true or false
        if (DataItem != null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

A suggested edit was posed in a similar fashion, however instead of a bool visibility, the visibility setting is altered by string value. I am sure they will add their take too. After all, variety is the spice of life

Answer (score 2):

Use codebehind, make the button visible when appropriate:

```
protected void gridview1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DataRow row = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
        string process = row.Field<string>("Process"); // change type from string to whatever it is
        Button btn = (Button) e.Row.FindControl("ButtonID");
        btn.Visible = process == "YourProcessValue";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can make use of RowDataBoundand than make decision of hiding your control

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            SomeObject mapItem = (SomeObject)e.Row.DataItem;
            if(!mapItem.Process)
                   (e.Row.Cells[3].FindControl("Buttonid") as Button).visible= false;
        }         
    }
```

or try

```
      <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Reject" 
            Visible='<%# ((bool)Eval("Process")) %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
```